# Why some black empty space in my drupal site bottom

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

in my Drupal site, some black, empty space is being displayed at the bottom of the page, like in the image below..

[image]

By googling, I understood, it is because not enough minimum content in the page. but did not get proper solution to fix it, ***except min-width setting*** in global (style.css) file, but it is displaying unnecessary scroll bars even a page has one row of data when you set that property.

Could any body suggest me a solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Surely just add the right background colour to your body tag in your css?

Answer (score 0):

in your style.css add

```
body {
  background: #f4f5e5;
}
```